# separate MVC project in to different projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with asp.net mvc project for a while now and have wondered something recently. Should my controllers and models and event the views be split out in to separate projects?

This is to enable total separation of the ui layer of the application. The project I am working will be a large scale application.

Opinions on this?

Answer (score 1):

> This is to enable total separation of the ui layer of the application

No, MVC is the frontend layer and if you want to separate the frontend from the rest of the application then leave the folders as they are and have separate projects that act as the other parts of your application. These other projects are typically dataaccess layer, business layer and domain object layer.